# How Buffered Streams works?

Tags: c#, java, stream, buffer, encapsulation

In Java and C# there are several classes for buffering streams:
`BufferedStream` in C#, `Buffered(Input|Output)Stream`  and `Buffered(Reader|Writer)`.

They gets some stream in constructor and implements the same interface.

The question is - how it works?

What happens, when I'm trying to read one byte? It reads a lot of bytes into inner buffer and then returns it to me byte after byte? On writing one byte? Writes into inner buffer and on `flush()` writes it to inner stream?

And about reading/writing an array of bytes - is it inefficient to do it on buffered streams cause of double copying bytes into and from inner array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It reads a lot of bytes into inner buffer and then returns it to me byte after byte?

Basically, yes.  It takes time to request data from disk platters or from a TCP stream, so it can be more efficient to get a whole chunk of bytes at once, rather than trying to retrieve them individually from the source.

Comment: So, buffered stream is useful if I'm reading a lot of bytes and want to read them byte after byte, not thinking about reading into buffer? And is useless if I want to read an array of bytes manually into my buffer?

Comment: Buffered stream is useful if your data source has some request overhead, and you want to limit the number of requests.  A hard drive takes about 1/120 of a second to completely rotate around, so if you retrieve 120 characters from it character-by-character, in the worst case it could take a whole second.  But if you retrieve all 120 characters at once, you can do it in a single rotation.  Sure, you can create your own buffer, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Note that a FileStream in .NET is already sufficiently buffered to use with a hard disk.  You only need `BufferedStream` if you're reading TCP packets from a socket, or something like that.

Comment: Just to be clear though: This is a transient buffer and isn't actually capturing the stream.